# or condition in replaceAll

Tags: java

I have a scenario, Where input file can have either \r\n as EOL or \n as EOL.

I want to replace these EOL with nothing so that I could get my multi-line file into single line. I'm not sure, In input file what could be the eol. It could be windows based or unix based.

So, I'm trying to do like this

```
string,replaceAll("\r\n","");
```

Is there any way I could use both type of EOL as OR condition in replaceAll at one time ? So that whenever it finds any EOL(\r\n or \n) just replace with ""?

Any suggestions ?

Comment: [Search for "Either X or Y"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
replaceAll("(\r\n|\n)","");
```

Or:

```
replaceAll("\r?\n","");
```